# What is the name of this series aired on AXN TV from the early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, tv

In the pilot episode, a middle aged obese man in standing in an underground subway and gets killed in a train accident. He is survived by his wife.

This man's heart/brain are transplanted into a young athletic good looking man (humanoid) who works for the police department and falls for the obese man's wife.

Comment: Could you clarify which aspects of this are scifi or fantasy? at present this is off topic

Comment: @AlexRobinson Sorry, did not understand. It is that part where a dead man is made alive into a humanoid which I have assumed will be on the lines of sci-fi.

Comment: @AlexRobinson Did you not read the second paragraph?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This was live-action?  How did they happen to have a spare hunky body sitting around?  Did.the dead guy have special skills that they revived him for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sounds like [*Now and Again*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_and_Again).

The show originally aired from September 1999 to May 2000 on CBS, but Wikipedia confirms it also aired on [AXN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AXN_(Indian_TV_channel)).

The only slight mismatch from your description is that the main character "works for" (but really is sort of owned by) a secret government organization, rather than the police.

Here is the plot synopsis from Wikipedia:

> Michael Wiseman (John Goodman in the pilot and flashbacks, and
> subsequently Eric Close) lives in suburban New York with his wife Lisa
> (Margaret Colin) and daughter Heather (Heather Matarazzo) and works as
> an executive at an insurance company. When passed over for a
> promotion, Michael and his friend and co-worker Roger (Gerrit Graham)
> go out drinking after work. **While standing on the subway platform
> heading home that night, Michael is accidentally knocked off the
> platform directly into the path of an oncoming train.** When he awakes,
> he sees Dr. Theodore Morris (Dennis Haysbert), the head of a top
> secret government **project to artificially engineer the perfect human
> body**. Unable to create a brain from scratch, **Dr. Morris has rescued
> Michael's brain from his dead body and implanted it in the engineered
> body**. The process allows Michael Wiseman to continue to live, but also
> forces him to work as an experiment for Dr. Morris and occasionally
> help fight terrorists. Because of the top-secret nature of the
> project, Michael is told he may never have contact again with his wife
> or daughter, under penalty of his own death and the death of anyone he
> tells of his existence. Despite the threat, **Michael finds ways to
> contact his family** while keeping his true identity a secret.

A recurring thread running throughout most episodes is Michael's feelings for his (former?) wife.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the show!!!!